Is it legal to print material from a public domain book that was later republished?
I am writing a student workbook and need primary sources for the students to read and analyze. Basically it lets students see the genuine perspectives of people who witnessed and wrote about a historic event.
I found one book written in the late 1800s, and the oldest copy I could find was published in 1921. I want to reprint a few of the very short chapters in my own book. But I discovered someone has reprinted the book again in the 1980s.
If I were to copy text from just the 1921 edition, is that still regarded as in the "public domain" or does the fact that a new edition has been reprinted later mean I can't legally use this text?
